# Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at 0x54b6)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, hpc

I am trying to remotely compile some code on a computing cluster, and I am getting the following error:

```
cd run_test; export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2; mpiexec -n 2 ./BATSRUS.exe > runlog
libibverbs: Warning: couldn't open config directory '/usr/etc/libibverbs.d'.
libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs0
libibverbs: Warning: couldn't open config directory '/usr/etc/libibverbs.d'.
libibverbs: Warning: couldn't open config directory '/usr/etc/libibverbs.d'.
libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs0
libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-
specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[57136,1],1]: A high-performance Open MPI point-to-point messaging module
was unable to find any relevant network interfaces:

Module: OpenFabrics (openib)
  Host: login001

Another transport will be used instead, although this may result in
lower performance.

NOTE: You can disable this warning by setting the MCA parameter
btl_base_warn_component_unused to 0.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[login001:44614:0:44614] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x54b6)
==== backtrace (tid:  44614) ====
=================================
[login001:44613:0:44613] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address 0x54b6)
==== backtrace (tid:  44613) ====
=================================
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node login001 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I will be honest that I have absolutely no idea what this means. This code compiles fine and runs fine on a local machine. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can solve this issue?

Comment: The remote machine does not have the -dev packages installed that are required for the build.

Comment: @bmargulies Could you elaborate? Are you seeing this from the other Warnings? Or is this a common issue when the "address not mapped" error occurs? Because I am getting a similar error but without such warnings. I'm running something on a super computer so I don't have any means to check packages. Maybe there's a way to figure out which package is missing? Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking at the warnings and assuming that the errors are consequences.